# doTry/doCatch and global onException behavior

Tags: apache-camel

I noticed that after successful `doTry/doCatch` handling global `onException` handler is no longer invoked. Here's my sample code:

```
<doTry>
    <to uri="direct:triggerError"/>
    <doCatch>
        <exception>com.foo.bar.MyException</exception>
        <log message="IN DOCATCH"/>
    </doCatch>
    <doFinally>
        <log message="IN FINALLY"/>
    </doFinally>
</doTry>

<throwException message="Now handle it in global handler" exceptionType="com.foo.bar.MyOtherException"/>
```

And in my camel context I have this:

```
<onException>
    <exception>com.foo.bar.MyOtherException</exception>
    <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <log message="HANDLING MY OTHER EXCEPTION"/>
    <to uri="direct:commonAPIErrorProcessor"/>
</onException>
```

What I observe is the exception is properly caught in `doCatch` and `doFinally` is invoked, but the global `onException` is never called and I get a stack trace in response. How can I fix it?
I tried it with Camel 3.4.0 and 3.7.0, same results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your example is that you **call another route within `doTry`**. This seems to confuse the Camel no matter if you use XML or Java DSL (in both DSLs the same effect).

As long as you use simple "statements" in `doTry`, everything works perfect. When you call another route, it is as you describe very confusing.

Camel catches the exception thrown by the other route, but afterwards the error handler stays "disabled". It seems like **Camel loses the `doTry` scope and therefore never finishes the "error handling disabled state" that is enabled by `doTry`**.

I therefore assume that the "route jump" is not the intended use case for [doTry/doCatch](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/try-catch-finally.html). Since it overwrites the normal error handling, it should probably be used only very locally within a route.

Comment: No, sorry, it makes no sense to me. I do understand that the exception raised inside `doTry` won't be handled by global `onException`, just like normal try/catch would work - but what I observe is that `onException` is never invoked when the exception is thrown after the `doTry` - that is, the last line of my sample code, `<throwException message="Now handle it in global handler" exceptionType="com.foo.bar.MyOtherException"/>` does not trigger my `onException` code - is it expected?

Comment: Missed your point, sorry. I have extended my answer

Comment: I just tried that, isolating doTry/doCatch into a separate route but it didn't help, I observe the same behavior.

Comment: And oddly enough, if I throw an exception directly from `doTry`, everything works as expected, but if from `doTry` I call a route that throws an exception, I observe the behavior described in my first post.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that my previous test was wrong. I rewrote the whole answer because the problem is the same in both DSLs